# "There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?" not showing in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Not a massive problem but something that has been bugging the life out of me...

One of my colleagues was trying out some code on my machine and got the "There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?" pop-up when the build failed on Visual Studio. He clicked on the "don't show this again" checkbox and closed the dialogue.

My problem is that I can't get the dialogue to show up again. I found these instructions online:

*"Select Tools, Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run. Then set the option "On run, when build or deployment errors occur" to Prompt to Launch."*

but that doesn't work. Resetting the IDE settings to default don't make any difference either.

Is there any way to get this dialogue back or has it gone forever?

Thanks,

K

Comment: NARA, but its lurking around there somewhere.  Which is a shame, as that dialog is annoying and I turn it off ASAP.  I hate that dialog with a passion rivaling... uh, something some famous historical person was really really passionate about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested to opt away the dialog, then bringing it back using that option, and it works just fine on my computer.

Try changing the option again, if that doesn't work something might be broken and you probably need to reinstall if you want the dialog back.

Comment: Thanks. Tried the old restart-of-system and it worked after that.

Comment: @Kevin: Right, a restart... I forgot to suggest that one. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the key:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\General\RunAfterBuildErrors
```

is set to 2. The value 2 is associated with *Prompt to launch* and the value 1 with *Do not launch*.